# Is evaluation of food healthiness on-topic?

Tags: discussion

This was closed:

https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/26117?noredirect=1#comment51623_26117

It seems totally valid to me: here's food (it has ingredients and nutrition information), and one would want to know if it is generally good for human consumption.

I *think* some medical scientists should be able to answer that. Was I mistaken? Why would it be considered spam?

Answer (score 4):

It's considered spam because it's little more than a link to a product advertisement where people can order the product (and others from the same company), it's loaded with popup ads, and then you ask if it's "ideal nutrition," which is advertising lingo that no medical professional is likely to ever use. You couldn't have constructed a question that looks more like spam *and has the same effect as spam* if you were trying to do so. I'm sure the Huel company would be very pleased to learn that someone posted a link to their advertising on a site like this.

But even if you didn't intend to spam the site, you need to visit the [help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help) and read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) There you will discover the following:

> Often asked questions that are off-topic include:
>
> - medical advice for yourself or others
> - **questions about nutrition and diet that aren't directly connected to medical treatment**
> - any other personal advice
> - interpretation of test results
> - treatment recommendations
> - second opinions.

So, spam or not, it's still off topic.

And finally, "ideal nutrition" is a matter of opinion, which also makes it off topic.

Comment: That's interesting. I should've have grabbed the nutrition facts and posted solely based on that. But that's still off topic. Do you know of any SE site where this question is on topic (assuming I will post a better question, i.e. with the actual nutrition facts and not linking to another site)?

Comment: @trusktr There is no site on SE I'm aware of that accepts nutrition questions, not even the cooking site. You're probably better off asking somewhere like quora or reddit.